# Etymology of "Green Paper" and similar expressions

Tags: etymology, word-usage

Is there any other similar expression beside **White Paper**, **Green Paper**, **Yellow Pages** and **Blue Book**? What is relation between their color and their meaning?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking for here. Can you clarify what you mean by "relation between their color and their meaning".

Comment: @Urbycoz I mean what is their etymology?

Comment: My guess would be pretty easy: the first (widely used) "*color* *subject*" was a *subject* that was colored in *color*. So the first "yellow pages" where pages, that where colored yellow.

Comment: It's also pretty common in technical writings. For example the standards related to compact discs (CDs) are described in the  [rainbow books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_Books) (red book = audio CD, yellow book = data CD, ...).

Comment: I think this is general reference, and am voting to close.

Comment: I think you are asking for a list of collocations of the form (colour adjective) + (paper), where 'paper' may be substituted by 'book' or a near-synonym, PLUS an explanation of what each refers to, and why, say, 'red card' and 'yellow card' are common expressions in the field of soccer, but 'violet card' isn't. You could do the research yourself - for instance, googling "yellow pages" gives a significant 28 000 000 hits, while "puce pages" returns a negligible 1500 or so. "Lateritious pages" scores a zero. "Little black book" is a three-word collocation you might investigate.

Comment: At least in the US "green paper" is used to mean paper made in "environmentally friendly" ways.  Perhaps by recycling previously-used paper.

Comment: @GEdgar http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_paper

Comment: example http://www.greenpaperstudio.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Green book - CCITT

Pages of gold (maybe not paper) - biblical metaphors

Black book(s) - out of favour. Noted for punitive action.

Little Black Book - contact list. ...

Blue (touch) paper - fireworks fuse
 Go to bed.
Somewhat contrived example** [Here ->](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=light%20the%20blue%20paper)

Purple paper - Canadian CCID (Collaborating Centre for Infectious Diseases)
[**H1N1 pandemic weekly newsletter.**](http://www.nccid.ca/purple-paper)

Black Paper - anti-education policy newsletters - name intended to contrast with white-paper. [**UK 1960s-1970s**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Papers)

Red Paper
**Canadian aboriginal peoples counter paper to Canadian government white paper** [* Here ...**](http://www.canadiana.ca/citm/_textpopups/aboriginals/doc75_e.html)

**Ugandan daily tabloid newspaper** [Here ...](http://www.mapsofworld.com/uganda/media/red-paper-uganda.html)

[**Also here**](http://www.shareaworksheet.com/download.php?file=49c4510fa7afa.pdf)

Purple pages - obscene, erotic. More recently = Gay friendly lists etc.
[Asheville Purple Pages](http://www.ashevillepurplepages.com/)

Comment: The Irish, unsurprisingly, have a _green paper_ (as apparently do the US) - a 'tentative government report and consultation document of policy'.  And we mustn't forget _brown paper_, especially if we're going up the hill for a pail of water. 'Little Red Book' is another three-word collocation.

Comment: The USAF uses the term "[dirty purples](http://allpme.com/)" to refer to study sheets written by – and distributed among – fellow students. Its etymology goes back to how they were at one time reproduced on mimeograph machines, which usually printed in purple ink. The name stuck long after photocopiers and electronic documents became the preferred method of reproduction and distribution. (I don't know if this really answers the O.P.'s question, but it seems related to Russell's answer, and some might find the history interesting.)